# Failing to install mingw: mingw-get-gui: *** ERROR *** unexpected end of archive reading header record

Tags: gcc, installation, mingw, archive

I am now trying to install mingw for a couple of hours, however I keep on getting the following error message:

"install: gcc-c++-4.8.1-4-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
 installing gcc-c++-4.8.1-4-mingw32-bin.tar.lzma
mingw-get-gui: *** ERROR *** unexpected end of archive reading header record"

and cannot find any solution to my problem. I tried to reinstall 7zip, because I thought it may caused from that. I am trying to install gcc on a 32-bit Windows 7. I would be really happy for any suggestions.

Bye!

Answer (score 2):

*Even though this is an old question, I will post an answer, in case other users come across this again.*

I encountered the same problem:

at first I did not notice that something went wrong with the installation/upgrade itself, because the graphical update manager showed a line like *"everything went successful"* ...

if I had bothered to look into the log details, I would have seen the error messesage `mingw-get-gui: * ERROR * unexpected end of archive reading header record` and immediately known, that something went wrong (its really misleading, to show a dialog saying that a task was completed successfully when there were errors!).

But pertaining to your problem (or at least this was, what caused mine):

### Cause

most likely something went wrong, when the mentioned archive file was downloaded. Unfortunately, `mingw-get` seems to ignore download errors and continues as if nothing went wrong... thus the error message *archive header record* is invalid, because it is not really an archive file, but a text file containing the HTML error message.

To complicate things further, `mingw-get` caches these files and when you try to re-install the packages it uses these invalid, cached files.

### Solution

One way of fixing this, would be to **delete the cached files** and then **re-install** the package.
The cached files should be at

```
<mingw directory>\var\cache\mingw-get\packages
```

e.g.
    C:\MinGW\var\cache\mingw-get\packages

> **Side Note:** if you "lost" the error message like me, and don't know, for which packages there was an error, you can search the cache directory for files which contain the HTML error message, e.g. a search term like `<html>` should work; also these files are quite small, but there may also be other valid packages with small file size to this is no unambiguous criterion

If you continue to get error messages `* ERROR * unexpected end of archive reading header record` with the `mingw-get` tool you could also try to download the file manually and place it in the folder for the cached packages.

For re-installing the packages you could use the graphical interface of `mingw-get` (e.g. remove and then install the package) or, for example the command line version

```
mingw-get --reinstall install <package name>
```

for `mingw` packages the `<package name>` is usually just the prefix of the file name (before the first version number), e.g. for

```
libiconv-1.14-3-mingw32-dev.tar.lzma
```

the package name would be `libiconv`. For `msys` packages the package name usually has the prefix `msys-`, e.g. something like `msys-libopts`

(you should be able to see if it's a `mingw` or a `msys` package by looking at the part of the file name that comes after the first version number, e.g. for `libiconv-1.14-3-mingw32-dev.tar.lzma`: `...3-mingw32-de...`)