# mingw issue "stddef.h :no such file or directory"

Tags: c, mingw

i install the MinGW and select those packet。
[image]
i also have using the command to check whether did i forget download some packet for install about GCC complier。

i also also have checking the path whether add  the C:\MinGW\bin or not.

[image]
when i think everything is ready, i make a helloword c file for testing

```
#include "stdio.h"
void main()
{
    printf("helloworld\n");
}
```

but when complies there is a error happen “stddef.h No such file....”

i knows there is a lot of posts about this issue here ，but i can't found anything way for solve this error....

i have also try to update the gcc and g++ version and make them same:

```
mingw-get update gcc g++
```

but it also doesn't work!

Comment: what about the 'mingw-get update' did not work?

Comment: @user3629249  it does not work, also i have try "mingw-get upgrade", but all of those cmd are not work

Answer (score 4):

It is with the version mismatch of gcc and g++.
First, we need to remove both the packages by executing below command in cmd.

`mingw-get remove gcc g++`

Then execute install to reinstall

`mingw-get install gcc g++`

hope this helps!!!

Comment: does not really help

Comment: install ran into another problem, had to clear the package cache, but then fine!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39247547/9437799